# Is there a way to detect the compiler version from within a Rust program?

Tags: rust

In C++, you could use something like `__clang_version__`. Is there something similar for Rust? I searched on the internet, but found nothing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you interested in what version of the compiler you are using?

Comment: Oh - I have some VS integrated rust version. Now I downloaded a new version of rust (1.7) and wondered if it is used by what I have in the IDE. So I thought - write 3 lines of codes and find out... ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not directly.

There is the [`rustc_version`](https://crates.io/crates/rustc_version) crate which tells you the version of `rustc` accessible on the command-line; this is designed to be used in a build script.  There's also [`rustc_version_runtime`](https://crates.io/crates/rustc_version_runtime) which does something similar, but exposes the information as a runtime call (*i.e.* it detects the compiler version at compile time, but exposes it at runtime).

Standard disclaimer: be *very* careful writing anything that depends on compiler version.  You should ideally only test for minimum versions for which features are supported using semver (which both of the above libraries support directly).