# How to add code only for specific Rust version without using a build script?

Tags: rust

I use a method that appeared in Rust 1.10 for my tests but I want my crate to also work with version 1.7.

Is there a way (something like attribute `#[cfg(min_version="1.10")]`) to specify code that should only run in Rust 1.10 or newer?

I could use a build script, but I don't want a more complicated build just because I wanted to test my crate on an older Rust version.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to detect the compiler version from within a Rust program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35806568/155423)?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the same. On this other question, the answers point at one crate for build scripts and the other crate to get the version at runtime. I want to output different code at compile time depending on the version. To put it another way: I want to use a function available at a specific rust version and fallback to another one if using an older compiler.

Comment: Are you aware that build scripts are run when the crate is compiled (a.k.a. compile time)? The [README for rustc-version](https://github.com/Kimundi/rustc-version-rs) literally has your example in it (search for `compiler_has_important_bugfix`) — testing to see if it is compiling against a specific version or better and setting a configuration flag that your code can then use.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I don't like having a more complicated build just because I wanted to test my crate on an older Rust version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no way except build scripts (and in the future procedural macros) to check compiler versions, you can use feature flags to manually enable and disable code.

Usually you want to use some new compiler feature to provide new functionality which you could not do with the old compiler. In that case you use the `cfg` attribute with feature flags which you define to enable code. E.g.

```
#[cfg(feature = "foo")]
pub fn foo() {
    cool_new_compiler_function();
}
```

And in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
foo = []
```

Hiding code behind feature flags like this also works in test code. In your specific case you could alternately introduce a `legacy` feature and disable tests using modern code like this:

```
#[test]
#[cfg(not(feature = "legacy"))]
fn test_foo() {
    Foo::foo();
}
```

And then to run tests in legacy mode you run:

```
cargo test --features "legacy"
```

Note that doing it the latter way means that your tests will not compile by default on older compilers. For normal (non-test) code, adding such a legacy flag would be a very bad, breaking change.

Comment: This forces *every downstream consumer* to set the flag as appropriate.

Comment: Do downstream consumers run your tests? If not they don't have to as far as I know. For non-test code I would do it the other way around. (I.e. "newstuff" feature, not "legacy")

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (especially with generic titles such as this one) are going to be found by people with a wide set of requirements, and they usually don't read past the title of the question before jumping to the first answer.

Comment: Besides, if OP wants to maintain compatibility with $OLDVERSION, then they should be testing in CI with both $OLDVERSION and $NEWVERSION, so at the very least OP has to deal with setting the flags appropriately.

Comment: Good point (regarding googlers), I'll add the general case *before* the specific one instead of after like I was going to. As for CI I think manually disabling tests to get them to pass is actually preferrable instead of having to do something akin to `cargo test --features "alltests"` which makes it very easy to accidentally not run all the tests.